# Showing multiple plot lines while displaying dual y-axis

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am having a highchart which shows multiple Y-Axis in opposite directions. It plots correctly but it shows separate lines for both of the axis.

This is for yAxis which I am plotting on highchart. I have set tried on highchart site and tried to replicate multiple lines on fiddle.

```
yAxises.push({
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: { text: ' ' },
        opposite: true,
        top: '0%',
        height: '100%',
        min: yAxises[0].min,
        max: yAxises[0].max,
        offset: 0
      });
```

I expect that if I have multiple y-axis with different min and max values then both min and max should be plotted on same line e.g.

```
YAxis -1             Y-Axis - 2

2 ------------------- 1.5

1 ------------------- 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the same `tickAmount` property for the y-axes or use `tickPositioner` function.

```
yAxis: [{
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    tickAmount: 3
}, {
    min: 0,
    max: 16,
    tickAmount: 3
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p12xj7zL/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickAmount